# Cannot add role and change nickname but bot is admin in guild

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to:

```py
isp = "new role1"
lis = [0, 'ingame_name', 'Real_first_name']
await message.author.add_roles(discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, name=isp))
await message.author.edit(nick=f"{lis[1]} ({lis[2]})")
```

And I'm getting `missing permissions` error.

I even tried on my alt with no admin in guild.

Comment: can you show the whole code?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of reason that can give you this error. Please check every case listed to see if you're in this situation :

##### Guild-side

- Your bot doesn't have the permissions required. Please check your guild settings, then roles, then check the role named after your bot. Note that having the Administrator permission bypass all other permissions, so apparently that's not your problem here.
- Your bot is lower that the member you're trying to edit. Verify that the highest role of your bot is higher than the highest role of the member you try to edit (in your case, the autor). The role hierarchy is dictated by the order of the roles in the guild settings, from top to bottom.

##### Discord-side

- Your bot doesn't have the `Server Members Intent` activated in the `Privileged Gateway Intents` section of the Discord developer portal. The intents are used for restrict access to certain informations for preventing abuses, so you have to activate them for having the link permissions. Got to the [Discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/), then select your bot, search for the `Server Members Intent`, and activate it.

##### Program-side

- Your bot doesn't have the `member` intent activated. Just like the intents in the developper portal, you have to precise the intents you want to use. [There are multiple way to do it](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html), but here's one :

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

I think the last two should be useful to you.

Comment: "Your bot is lower that the member you're trying to edit." - the thing which solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you invited your bot to your server, you didn't add the permissions function in the discord developer portal. If it isnt this problem, it might be that the admin roles have some issues and you should make a new admin role for the bot. But im pretty sure you didn't give the bot certain permissions.

[image]